# Enable to get bucket location, using default endpoint

Tags: amazon-s3, ssis, script-task

I have a script task in SSIS 2008 which should upload data from S3 Bucket.
Now, I faced an issue and receive such error:

> GetRegionCode - unable to get bucket location, using default endpoint:
> s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com System.Exception: Request was redirected,
> new location is , new region is eu-west-1

I checked C# Code and see that we have specified correct location:

[image]

```
    {
  try {
    using(AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
              accessKey, secretKey, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1)) {
      ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();
      request.BucketName = bucketName;
```

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image.

Comment: I attached the code here:



  {
                try
                {
                    using (AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1))
                    {
                        ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();
                        request.BucketName = bucketName;